# How do I develop for Azure without using a live SQL Azure instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a BizSpark account and I get some Azure freebies from Microsoft. But, I'm forced to create a live SQL Azure database to use in my local development. This slows me down a bit because I have to read/write over the wire when I'm developing, and I must remain connected at all times.

Is there a way, or a technique, to build locally and have my deployments access the express edition of SQL Server on my machine? I'm using EF4 to access the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, as a part of Bizspark, you get 3 SQL Azure databases for free. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ee461076.aspx
This will allow you to have 1 DB for testing, 1 for dev, and 1 for production

If this does not work out for you, you CAN develop on your local SQL Express and keep deploying your changes to SQL Azure as you deploy your application to Azure.  There are two tools that help you here:
1) open-source SQL Azure Migration Wizard: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/  -- we personally do not use this for deployments, so I am not super knowledgeable to comment on this.  It is a decent tool to back your SQL Azure database.
2) You can use [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/)'s SQL Compare product, as of v9.0+, they support synchronizing cross SQL Azure and on-prem SQL servers.  We use this for [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) and are very happy.  It is commercial product and is somewhat pricey.

HTH

Comment: Yes, I'm happy with Bizspark's free databases, but I'm not always online when traveling around with my laptop. So I think I will continue working with SQL Server 2008 Express on my local machine and manually synchronise using the SQL Azure Migration Wizard when I'm connected.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Igorek's answer - plenty of good suggestions there.

In addition to his advice, if you are a BizSpark licensee then I suggest you deploy full SQL Server 2008 R2 to a local box and develop against that.

There are differences between full SQL Server and SQL Azure - you should read around to be aware of these - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/comparing-sql-server-with-sql-azure.aspx

As long as you are aware of the differences (especially the SQL Azure limitations) then migrating back to SQL Azure later, should be reasonable.